# How to parse an URI elegantly in Casablanca

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rest, boost, casablanca

How would one parse the URI of a request (server side) elegantly in C++?

URI is defined as in the [Casablanca Documentation](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=URI) as:

> protocol : // server [: port] / path ? query # fragment

Lets say, i want the path (with all elements) as a list and the queries as a list of key/value pairs so

> http://server/foo/bar?val1=1&val2=yo

would result in

```
std::list<string> path;
path.push_back("foo");
path.push_back("bar");

std::list<std::pair<string, string>> query;
query.push_back(std::make_pair("val1", "1"));
query.push_back(std::make_pair("val2", "yo"));
```

I want to avoid doing the parsing myself like proposed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148667/parse-rest-query-in-c), mostly for portability and performance reasons.

[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/in_depth/uri.html) does not seem to be [part of boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform) yet and i'd prefer not to introduce a new library.

Casablanca has an [URI](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1uri.html) object, but i cant find any parsing or iterators.

Is there a way to solve this using only boost, c++, casablanca/cpprestsdk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that there are static helper functions in the URI class, e.g. [uri::split_query](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1uri.html#a48d1bb49e4c518aebbff5e5da812ffbf) and [uri::split_path](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1uri.html#a62fa1329d441eb6e176ede47692aec91) that perform exactly as requested.

I found references to them after looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SeanCline/6005128) which uses

```
auto http_get_vars = uri::split_query(request.request_uri().query());
```